# Scrapy FormRequest with playload

Tags: python, post, scrapy, spyder

I am trying to scrape a web passing 10002 zipcode.
Here is my Scrapy Spyder

```
class HoytSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
name = "hoyt_usa"
allowed_domains = ["hoyt.com"]
start_urls = ["http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer"]

def parse(self, response):
    url = 'http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer'
    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    headers['Cookie'] = '__cfduid=db974b4cdb2e79ef45abf70b16fd9b83e1494447240; PHPSESSID=3re29iv8ejkl9fapv1kqk28jk7; _dc_gtm_UA-28625097-1=1; _ga=GA1.2.689069018.1494447289; _gid=GA1.2.581535200.1494451642; _gat_UA-28625'
    headers['Referer'] = 'http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer'
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
    payload = {'hoyt_dealer_basic_search%5Bzip%5D':'10002', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search%5Bradius%5D':'50', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search%5Bgo%5D': '', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search%5B_token%5D': 'FxDqyxsyOtDcLHBhsY1AR49Zhq9Oj2rmPeDxPvq0chg', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search%5Bemail_address%5D': ''}
    return FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='hoyt_dealer_basic_search', headers=headers, formdata=payload, callback=self.parse_dealers)

def parse_dealers(self, response):
    print '+++++++++++'
    html = response.xpath('//div[@class="row content-row"]//div[@class="medium-3"]')
    print len(html)
    print response.body
```

I have some html in response body, but with no results. I also tried Formdata(url, headers=headers, formdata=payload) - but that also didn't help
I suppose I hane some issue with passing payload with response. 
Any ideas? Will be much appreciated

Response should contain var theMarkers = [items]. Now theMarkers is empty

Answer (score 1):

You need to use non-URL-encoded keys for your form data:

```
payload = {
 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[Bemail_address]': '',
 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[_token]': 'FxDqyxsyOtDcLHBhsY1AR49Zhq9Oj2rmPeDxPvq0chg',
 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[go]': '',
 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[radius]': '50',
 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[zip]': '10002'}
```

Example scrapy shell session:

```
>>> url = 'http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer'
>>> headers = {}
>>> headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>>> headers['Cookie'] = '__cfduid=db974b4cdb2e79ef45abf70b16fd9b83e1494447240; PHPSESSID=3re29iv8ejkl9fapv1kqk28jk7; _dc_gtm_UA-28625097-1=1; _ga=GA1.2.689069018.1494447289; _gid=GA1.2.581535200.1494451642; _gat_UA-28625'
>>> headers['Referer'] = 'http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer'
>>> headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
>>> payload = {'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[zip]':'10002', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[radius]':'50', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[go]': '', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[_token]': 'FxDqyxsyOtDcLHBhsY1AR49Zhq9Oj2rmPeDxPvq0chg', 'hoyt_dealer_basic_search[Bemail_address]': ''}

>>> frq = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='hoyt_dealer_basic_search', headers=headers, formdata=payload)
>>> fetch(frq)
2017-05-11 10:10:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer> (referer: http://hoyt.com/find-a-dealer)


>>> print(response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[2])

        //Generate Markers Value Array
        var theMarkers = [
                                                {"title":'Gotham Archery',"lat": '40.684381',"lng": '-73.980437',"description":
                        '<strong>Gotham Archery</strong><br />480 Baltic Street'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Pro Line Archery Lanes, Inc.',"lat": '40.684494',"lng": '-73.850427',"description":
                        '<strong>Pro Line Archery Lanes, Inc.</strong><br />9511 101st Ave'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Queen`s Archery',"lat": '40.760434',"lng": '-73.799188',"description":
                        '<strong>Queen`s Archery</strong><br />170-20 39TH Ave'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Targeteers SG2, Inc.',"lat": '40.902033',"lng": '-74.100102',"description":
                        '<strong>Targeteers SG2, Inc.</strong><br />P O Box 878'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Extreme Archery, Inc.',"lat": '40.955281',"lng": '-73.737657',"description":
                        '<strong>Extreme Archery, Inc.</strong><br />801 East Boston Post Rd'}
                ,                                     {"title":'C &amp; B Archery',"lat": '40.766663',"lng": '-73.516470',"description":
                        '<strong>C &amp; B Archery</strong><br />11 Commercial Street'}
                ,                                     {"title":'American Outdoor Sports',"lat": '40.725297',"lng": '-73.444737',"description":
                        '<strong>American Outdoor Sports</strong><br />238 Route 109'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Davis Sport Shop',"lat": '41.160697',"lng": '-74.189154',"description":
                        '<strong>Davis Sport Shop</strong><br />P.O. Box 87'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Heritage Guild Branchburg',"lat": '40.543740',"lng": '-74.660040',"description":
                        '<strong>Heritage Guild Branchburg</strong><br />3321 Hwy 22 East'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Garden State Bow &amp; Reel',"lat": '41.088300',"lng": '-74.514420',"description":
                        '<strong>Garden State Bow &amp; Reel</strong><br />2760A Route 23 North'}
                ,                                     {"title":'A &amp; M Archery',"lat": '40.084328',"lng": '-74.203837',"description":
                        '<strong>A &amp; M Archery</strong><br />201 2nd Street'}
                ,                                     {"title":'Simon Peter Sport, CO.',"lat": '41.036057',"lng": '-74.764550',"description":
                        '<strong>Simon Peter Sport, CO.</strong><br />660 Route 206 South'}
                                                    ];
        var theMapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.715523, -73.988379),
                        zoom: 8
        };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!